# Understanding reselect in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reselect

I was going through the article by [Dan Parker](https://medium.com/@parkerdan/react-reselect-and-redux-b34017f8194c) on Medium about reselect npm module.

In the advance stage section of his code, He has given this example (with comment)

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'
// I am a generic selector, I need no special treatment
// I am now passing props so I can find a specific bar
const getBar = (state, props) => {
  const id = props.id
  const barById = state.foo.bar.find((item,i) => item.id === id)
  return barById
}
// This no longer will work if it is needed in multiple places
//export const getBarState = createSelector(
//  [ getBar ],
//  (bar) => bar
//)
// This is proper if it is needed in multiple instances
export const makeGetBarState = () => createSelector(
  [ getBar ],
  (bar) => bar
)
```

I am unable to comprehend above code,like here

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'
```

We are importing createSelector from reselect.

```
const getBar = (state, props) => {
  const id = props.id
  const barById = state.foo.bar.find((item,i) => item.id === id)
  return barById
}
```

here, I am unable to get from where/how we are getting `props`.

and why would this not work

```
export const getBarState = createSelector(
  [ getBar ],
  (bar) => bar
)
```

but this would

```
export const makeGetBarState = () => createSelector(
  [ getBar ],
  (bar) => bar
)
```

Answer (score 2):

> here, I am unable to get from where/how we are getting props.

props can be passed to `getBar` from mapStateToProps:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    todos: getBar(state, props)
  }
}
```

---

> and why would this not work

doesn't return a new copy of `getBar`

```
export const getBarState = createSelector(
  [ getBar ],
  (bar) => bar
)
```

> but this would

returns a new copy of the `getBar`

```
export const makeGetBarState = () => createSelector(
  [ getBar ],
  (bar) => bar
)
```

You would want to return a new copy when you need to share a selector across multiple instances while passing in props and retaining memoization, where each instance of the component needs its own private copy of the selector.